# Why does clicking an accordion item open all items?

Tags: vue.js, accordion

I tried to implement the below into my project. I double-checked and I cannot see any flaw in my implementation. Yet in my case, a click on one item opens all items of the accordion. Why?

Below is my code.

Markup:

```
<div
  v-for="item in faqItems"
  :key="item.id"
  class="faq-item"
  @click="toggle"
>
  <transition
    name="accordion"
    @before-enter="beforeEnter"
    @enter="enter"
    @before-leave="beforeLeave"
    @leave="leave"
  >
    <div v-show="show" class="faq-item-details">
      <div class="faq-item-details-inner" v-html="item.text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </transition>
</div>
```

JS:

```
methods: {
  toggle () {
    this.show = !this.show
  },
  beforeEnter (el) {
    el.style.height = '0'
  },
  enter (el) {
    el.style.height = el.scrollHeight + 'px'
  },
  beforeLeave (el) {
    el.style.height = el.scrollHeight + 'px'
  },
  leave (el) {
    el.style.height = '0'
  }
}
```

Comment: You code snippet works well

Comment: That's because someone edited my question and replaced my code with the demo code. I just undid that and pasted my code as I did initially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the same `show` for all accordions.
You can use separate components (see answer from [@Moisés Hiraldo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55042069/5783475)) or use the following logic:

HTML

```
<div
  v-for="item in faqItems"
  :key="item.id"
  class="faq-item"
  @click="toggle(item.id)"
>
  ...
     <div v-show="showItems[item.id]" class="faq-item-details">
```

JS

```
data() {
  return {
    showItems: {}
  }
},
methods: {
  toggle (id) {
     const newVal = !this.showItems[id]
     this.$set(this.showItems, id, newVal)
  }
}
```

**If you need only one opened item**
HTML

```
<div
  v-for="item in faqItems"
  :key="item.id"
  class="faq-item"
  @click="select(item.id)"
>
  ...
     <div v-show="item.id === selectedItemId" class="faq-item-details">
```

JS

```
data() {
  return {
    selectedItemId: null
  }
},
methods: {
  select(id) {
    this.selectedItemId = this.selectedItemId !== id ? id : null
  },
},
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure I understand your code though. Is `showItems` an array and is it empty?

Comment: It is an empty object.
You can use the array but in this case you need logic to add/remove items from it.

Comment: When you click to the item first time object will be `{ 'id_of_clicked_item', true }` and this code `showItems[item.id]` will return `true`

Comment: After the second click result will be `{ 'id_of_clicked_item', false}`

Comment: I guess one at a time. For now when I click an item after implementing the logic you propose, nothing happens (I get no console error either)

Comment: I forget a return inside the data block. See updates

Comment: There are two `data() {}` now. I'm confused :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189595/discussion-between-pvl-and-drake035).

Answer (score 1):

I would expect that code to open all items when you click one. The reason is they're all inside the same component, so they all access the same `this.show` variable.

You could have your main component as an accordion container than renders each element as a separate component, each one with its own `this.show` variable:

```
<accordion-item
  v-for="item in faqItems"
  :key="item.id"
  :item="item"
>
```